# nature of Python's logging module

Tags: python, logging

I understand that Python's [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) is synchronous.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

If it is synchronous, and I am using it to write time stamps a log file, will it write the time when the write was called or will it write the time stamp of the the time when the write to disk happens

For example in a heavy write scenario if I call the log write at "n" time and the actual write happens at "n+2" seconds, in the log file will it use "n" as time stamp or will it use "n+2" as time stamp

Answer (score 0):

The order of writing at "n" time in some specific log file has been sent to the OS.

So, as far as I know python cant control the process between, let's say, `logging.debug("Logging "%s" % datetime.datetime.now()` until it's finally written in the file.

So it would make sense to expect some delay and in heavy scenarios we could have heavy delay.

Comment: What do you think will happen if I do the same from a low level language implementation such as c

Comment: Well there are several things you could try. You could use stdout instead logging into a file to see if the speed changes.

Writing into a file is sometimes an expensive task for the machine, if the file is too big, or the machine has hard drive problems it may slow down the logging.

And if the disk IO seems to be a problem you could of course write a simple C program with writes unformatted data to a file, that would be very fast and accurate.

But at the end of the day the IO of the disk is very important too and it hasnt anything to do with C or Python.

Comment: Also I am thinking you could use something like this http://www.machinalis.com/blog/rt-notifications-gevent-gis/ forgetting the Django part and using gevent-socketio and Redis with RabbitMQ instead writting into a logging file.